# Chrome Extensions - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it so my button may only open one instance of my webpage at one time but it refuses to work. I am in the process of debugging and I was under the impression if I close the tab I opened using my button, both alerts should print the same number (the tab id (which is unique no?)). They don't. Here is my code..

```
var isOpen = false;
var myTabId = null;

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, removeInfo){
    if (isOpen == true)
    {
        alert(myTabId);
        alert(tabId);

    }
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (isOpen == false)
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': "./selectpage.html"});
        isOpen = true;
        myTabId = tab.id;

        alert("new tab "+tab.id);

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that you're storing the incorrect Tab id in myTabId.  In the onClicked callback, you are being passed a reference to the Tab that was active when your extension icon was clicked - not the new tab you are opening in response.

What you should do is add a callback for when the new tab is created, and store a reference to its id:

```
var isOpen = false;
var myTabId = null;

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, removeInfo){
    if (isOpen == true)
    {
        alert(myTabId);
        alert(tabId);

    }
});    

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (userTab) {
    if (isOpen == false)
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': "./selectpage.html"}, function(myTab){
            isOpen = true;
            myTabId = myTab.id;

            alert("new tab "+myTabId);
        });
    }
});
```